# MTP initialization fails when same key is used to sign all Android components

Tags: key, android-5.0-lollipop, android-image

I'm working on customizing Android for my client and in process I need to re-sign the complete Android source (Android L)

To do this I use AOSP prescribed mechanism and sign using AOSP scripts as below :

1. `sign_target_files_apks --default_key_mapping $PROD_KEY_DIR --replace_ota_keys $OTA_KEY $OTA_DIR/signed_targetfile_new.zip`
2. `img_from_target_files $OTA_DIR/signed_targetfile_new.zip $OTA_DIR/signed_img_new.zip`

Following this http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/release_keys.html

This works fine for me if I keep keys different, however when I keep all the keys as same (`media=shared=platform=release`) I get a failure during MTP initilaization.

```
<12>[610.251814] type=1400 audit(1423670824.756:7): avc: denied { read write } for 
pid=2216 comm="d.process.media" name="mtp_usb" dev="tmpfs" ino=9911 
scontext=u:r:platform_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:mtp_device:s0 tclass=chr_file result=0
```

Can somebody tell me if there is any specific constraint or change required when using same keys.